# How to fix Visual Studio 2019 "The C# Project is targeting ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0", which is not installed on this machine

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-2.0

I have installed VS2019 on the E: drive of my machine rather than the smaller c: boot drive. I had it installed before I Wiped the machine on the c: drive and it took up WAY to much space. Now It gives me this error message AND WILL NOT allow me to pick any targeting .NET Framework on C# WFA before 4. I have NO Idea what to do, Ive followed the advice and went to the website listed and manually downloaded the .NET Core SDK for 2.0 and installed it, then tried to repair it, and it JUST KEEPS SAYING ITS NOT INSTALLED, the project needs .net 2.0 to work. Am I gonna have to wipe the WHOLE computer again and take up ALL the space on my boot drive to get this damn thing to work? I just don't understand, It does this on enterprise & community, how the hell can Microsoft NOT excpect an ENTERPRISE to install VS 2019 ON another drive then the boot drive, ESPECIALLY WHEN ALL THE TOOLS YOU NEED ARE GARGANTUAN.

IVE TRIED EVERYTHING THE ERROR MESSAGE SAYS. there are 2 options it gives to load the project, 1. DOWNLOAD the sdk manually for .NET FRAMEWORK 2.0 WHICH IVE INSTALLED AND REPAIRED, 2. CHANGE THE PROJECT TO .NET 4.0, WHICH I CANNOT DO. or the worst option JUST CLOSE THE SOLUTION

I want to be clear that I Have another machine that this project pulls up perfectly with VS 2019 and I know people are gonna jump to the Microsoft doesn't support something that old bandwagon. It gives me the option to target .NET Framework 2.0 on the other machine RIGHT NOW, and did on this one for VS 2019 Community AND ENTERPRISE BEFORE INSTALLING ON AN OTHER THAN BOOT DRIVE, so wheteher they TECHNICALLY SUPPORT IT IN ALL THE DOCUMENTATION IS A VOID ARGUMENT, it worked perfectly before on this exact machine, and does an another one with VS 2019, if it was a support issue I seriously doub MS would give an error messae saying to install .net 2.0, I knew installing CORE probably wouldn't work, but that's the websit it sent me to.The point is they DID just 2 days ago, Microsoft randomly stops supporting legacy features like that on an ENTE#RPRISE PRODUCT with NO warning after release? Now I see why a lot of c++ people DESPISE VS.

Answer (score 1):

If something in your project absolutely requires the .NET framework 2.0, try installing it from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19988 (this is NOT .NET Core)

Comment: yes found it thanks. I know they really don't like people using 2.0 but I have no interest in redoing esc/pos encoding on a new version, thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2019 doesn’t support older .NET Framework versions than 3.5, see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/compatibility#developWindows). If you really need .NET 2.0 you need to install an older Visual Studio that has support for that version.

.NET Core is completely different thing than .NET Framework 2.0 so installing that doesn’t help.

This has nothing to do with where you install applications.

Also note that support for 2.0 has ended a decade ago so if this project is needed it would be highly recommended to update it into a newer version. There usually aren’t many reasons why this cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it for anyone that EVER has this problem again, you've got to search through some deprecated websties but im absolutely sure If you've made it this far you can figure out how to install the .net faramework 2.0 sdk if you just search hard enough lol